# Why am i getting undefined error while trying to create a new Bootcamp?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am developing an API in node js and i am now doing the CRUD methods.

For any reason when i try to create a new `Bootcamp` i get undefined error.

This is my controller:

```
const Bootcamp = require('../models/Bootcamp');

// @desc    Create a new Bootcamp
// @route   POST /api/v1/bootcamps
// @access  Private

exports.createBootcamp = async (req, res, next) => {
   const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.create(req.body);

    res.status(201).json({
        success: true, 
        data: bootcamp
    });
}
```

The issue is at `const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.create(req.body);` due that if i `console.log(req.body)` i get the correct data that i am sending through postman.

The following is the data i am sending:

```
{
        "name": "Devworks Bootcamp",
        "description": "Devworks is a full stack JavaScript Bootcamp located in the heart of Boston that focuses on the technologies you need to get a high paying job as a web developer",
        "website": "https://devworks.com",
        "phone": "(111) 111-1111",
        "email": "enroll@devworks.com",
        "address": "233 Bay State Rd Boston MA 02215",
        "careers": ["Web Development", "UI/UX", "Business"],
        "housing": true,
        "jobAssistance": true,
        "jobGuarantee": false,
        "acceptGi": true
    }
```

And the following is my model `Bootcamp`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const BootcampSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a name'],
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        maxLength: [50, 'Name cannot be more than 50 characters']
    },
    slug: String,
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a description'],
        maxLength: [500, 'Description cannot be more than 500 characters']
        
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
        match: [
            /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/,
            'Please use a valid URL with HTTP or HTTPS'
        ]
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        maxLength: [20, 'Phone number cannot be longer than 20 characters']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        match: [
            /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/,
            'Please add a valid email'
        ]
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an address']
    },
    location: {
        type: {
            //GeoJSON Point
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point'],
            required: true
        },
        coordinates: {
            type:  [Number],
            required: true,
            index: '2dsphere'
        },
        formattedAddress: String,
        street: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        zipcode: String,
        country: String
    },
    careers: {
        //Array of strings
        type: [String],
        required: true,
        enum: [
            'Web Development',
            'Mobile Development',
            'UI/UX',
            'Data Science',
            'Business',
            'Other'
        ]
    },
    averageRating: {
        type: Number,
        min: [1, 'Rating must be at least 1'],
        max: [10, 'Rating must can not be more than 10']
    },
    averageCost: Number,
    photo: {
        type: String,
        default: 'no-photo.jpg'
    },
    housing: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    jobAssistance: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    jobGuarantee: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    acceptGi: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bootcamp', BootcampSchema);
```

As i send the data i get in my console `Error undefined` and the app crashes

Comment: always use a try catch block in your async function. in the catch block log the error and see what it is